# Magento 2 checkout page label change

Tags: magento2, checkout, checkout-page

How to change checkout page label state/province to Delivery location anyone help me[image]

Comment: Very urgent anyone help me

Comment: which version you are using it?

Answer (score 1):

I have assume that your magento version 2. So check below answer.

```
Translation for State/Province and Zip/Postal Code is found (by default) in /vendor/magento/module-checkout/i18n directory.

You can copy locale's csv file from /vendor/magento/module-checkout/i18n folder to app/code/Magento/module-checkout/i18n directory.

Then find the text and change its translation.

After saving file, don't forget to remove content from /var/cache folder and /var/page_cache folder
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this below way :

Create **di.xml** file at `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="checkout_lbl_change" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type> 
</config>
```

Create **LayoutProcessor.php** file at `app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/LayoutProcessor.php` :

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class LayoutProcessor
{
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array $jsLayout
    ) {
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
        ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['region_id']['label'] = __('Delivery location');

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: unfortunately is not working

Comment: Did you clean cache?

Comment: yes sir cache and flush are already cleaned but no change

Comment: my version is 2.3.4 is it possibile??

Comment: Yes. Plugin work in all version. Maybe it's theme related issue. Not sure.

Comment: Please check with your luma theme instance.

Comment: i already change luma theme to firezy theme

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105687/discussion-between-rohan-hapani-and-manu).